# What's the best way to inject JWT for API Calls in Nuxt.js?

Tags: api, vue.js, jwt, axios, nuxt.js

I'm creating a Frontend with nuxt.js where all my relevant data is fetched from an API. For Authorization I'm using JSON Web Tokens and I'm wondering what would be the best way to inject the JWT to the Request. The JWT gets signed with a Key, but how can I assure that the signing process only gets called on the server-side and is not exposed on the client-side? I tried the `servermiddleware` from nuxt and wrote my own middleware with express but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go.

Another thing I'm currently playing around is the `asyncData` inside of my component but the last part of the explanation makes me a bit suspicious.

```
It will be called server-side once (on the first request to the 
Nuxt app) and client-side when navigating to further routes.
```

So what would be the best practice to fetch data from an API but before actually fetching adding a JWT for Authorization? 
Thanks for any advises

Answer (score 0):

Try [nuxt-auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) module. I think it answers your broad questions.